# jQuery chained events aren't firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

When I run this in Chrome, "A" and "B" are logged successfully, but the program never reaches "C". Why is that?

```
function doSomething(){
    var chain   = $.Deferred();

    console.log("B");

    chain.then(function(){
        console.log("C");
    }).then(function(){
        console.log("D");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("body").click(function(){
        console.log("A")
        doSomething();
    });

});
```

I've spent the past 30 minutes trying to find an answer, but everything seems to beyond what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well you did nothing with the Deferred.

Answer (score 3):

You should call [.resolve](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/), like this

```
function doSomething(){
    var chain   = $.Deferred();

    console.log("middle");

    chain.then(function(){
        console.log("end");
    });

    chain.resolve();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm confused, though, because I ran something very similar to this that had no .resolve or .reject -- just several .then -- and it worked. Are there situations in which .resolve is implied or something?

Comment: @robertgfthomas Some asynchronous methods such as `ajax`, `load`, `get` and even `animate` return a promise that the *"resolved"* is called when it end.

Comment: @robertgfthomas could you give example where have you used Deferred without  .resolve ?

Comment: @Alexander You know what, I actually did include .resolve. That's always fun, when I learn how to do something and then promptly forget everything about it two days later.

Answer (score 3):

The `$(document).ready` event is fired when the document loads, handled by jQuery, so that one is called pretty early on. It then binds a `click` handler to `body`, which is fired when a click event is detected. That logs "start" and immediately calls `doSomething`, which creates a `Deferred` and logs "middle".

You never actually *do* anything with that `Deferred`, however. You bind a callback when it is resolved, but never [resolve](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) it. Thus, the callback is never fired.

Returning the `Deferred` and calling its `resolve` method (with or without args) should fix this. You may want to call it later, from a timeout, or immediately with args from the event. Either way, you need to resolve (or reject) the promise at some point.

```
function doSomething(){
  var chain = $.Deferred();

  console.log("middle");

  chain.then(function(){
    console.log("end");
  });

  return chain;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").click(function(){
    console.log("start")
    var dfd = doSomething();
    dfd.resolve();
  });
});
```